# NEW TO SQL, INSERT INTO 'TABLE' Error

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL, there's an error in my syntax that I don't understand. Any help/suggestions?

I created a table called ACCOUNT

```
CREATE TABLE `ACCOUNT` (
  `acc_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `acc_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `acc_manager` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `acc_balance` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `acc_transactionLimit` INT NOT NULL,
  `acc_creditLimit` INT NOT NULL,
  `OUTLET_out_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`acc_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_ACCOUNT_OUTLET1_idx` (`OUTLET_out_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ACCOUNT_OUTLET1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OUTLET_out_ID`)
    REFERENCES `OUTLET` (`out_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

No problems so far. But when i try to insert records into the table i get the following error:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (Database.ACCOUNT, CONSTRAINT fk_ACCOUNT_OUTLET1
>   FOREIGN KEY (OUTLET_out_ID) REFERENCES OUTLET (out_ID))

I checked back on my OUTLET reference table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `OUTLET` (
  `out_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `out_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `out_manager` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `out_address` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `out_phone` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `out_email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`out_ID`))
```

I didn't find any problems with it.

Yet when trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(acc_ID, acc_name, acc_manager, acc_balance, acc_transactionLimit, acc_creditLimit) VALUES
( 01, 'White', 'Mr.Good', '352.00', 1000.00, 500.00),
( 02, 'Hopkins', 'Mr.Good', '403.00', 1000.00, 500.00),
( 03, 'Aumbry', 'Mr.Good', '240.00', 1000.00, 500.00), 
( 04, 'Kaze', 'Mr.Good', '76.00', 1000.00, 500.00), 
( 05, 'Ashley', 'Mr.Bad', '24.00', 1000.00, 500.00), 
( 06, 'Zoara', 'Mr.Bad', '503.00', 1000.00, 500.00), 
( 07, 'Shawn', 'Mr.Bad', '34.00', 1000.00, 500.00), 
( 08, 'Obsie', 'Mr.Bad', '278.00', 1000.00, 500.00), 
( 09, 'Ven', 'Mr.Mr.Bad', '345.00', 1000.00, 500.00), 
( 10, 'Zhan', 'Mr.Mr.Bad', '491.00', 1000.00, 500.00);
```

I get the error stated above.

Comment: do you have data in any of the tables? This usually causes this kind of error to occur.

Comment: As a pure aside, it is worth noting that MySQL is only one type of SQL databases and there are many SQL databases available.

Comment: You've declared OUTLET_out_ID as a foreign key, but your inserts don't have any assignments to it.

Comment: This is made from scratch, all the tables are currently empty, i've retried droping the tables and recreating them again, could it be something else?

Comment: I'm looking into it, thanks for the replies so far.

Comment: Basically, unless you set that column to a value that's already present in the OUTLET table, I don't think the insert will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert data into the **Outlet** table that the `OUTLET_out_ID` references, as this is a `NON-NULL` column but is a `foreign key` but no key has yet been made, so you need to re-order your inserts accordingly.

You also can't skip this value because it's `NON-NULL` and your current inserts are failing as you're not giving it a valid Foreign Key reference.

Insert data into the source table of your foreign key constraints *First* and then the Account data *second*.

Additionally, the data inserted into the Outlet table needs to correspond to the values referenced in the Accounts table, as dictated by a foreign key.

---

Personally I think it's easier in these data insert situations to simply tinsert the data without FK constraints and add these conditions after the data has been inserted. Personally.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been nice to see your `OUTLET` table script; but then there's something more obvious here: the field `OUTLET_out_ID` is set to `NOT NULL` and your INSERT script does not have value for that field.

So, either modify that field to `OUTLET_out_ID INT NULL` or include the values in your `INSERT` query.

Comment: I had an error in my submission i meant to show the OUTLET table script aswell, edited and corrected for future reference. I think i understand better my problem now. Thanks for the feedback and help.